# OpenCV Running Video from WebCam on different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, pthreads

I have 2 webcams and I want to get input from both of them at the same time. Therefore I believe I have to work with threads in c++ which is pthread. When I run my code given below, the webcam turns on for a second and the routine exits. I can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

```
void *WebCam(void *arg){

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    for (; ; ) {
        Mat frame;
        *cap >> frame;
        resize(frame, frame, Size(640, 480));
        flip(frame, frame, 1);

        imshow("frame", frame);

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);   
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &WebCam, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

this is doe for one webcam just to turn and do streaming. Once this one works than other will be just copy of it.

Comment: why do you think, you need threads at all ? not nessecarily true.

Comment: why are you trying to deref cap ?

Comment: I reformatted/edited your code, and as @ChronoTrigger noticed below, all you have to do is add ``pthread_join(thread1, NULL);`` before ``return 0;``.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the thread, it starts running, but your main program, which is still running, just terminates, making the child thread finish too. Try adding this after `pthread_create`:

```cpp
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
```

By the way, even if you have two cameras, you can avoid the use of threads. I am not sure, but they could be problematic when dealing with the highgui functions (`imshow`, `waitKey`), because you must make sure they are thread-safe. Otherwise, what will be the result of having two threads calling `waitKey` at the same time?
You could get rid of threads with a design similar to this one:

```cpp
VideoCapture cap0(0);
VideoCapture cap1(1);

for(;;)
{
  cv::Mat im[2];
  cap0 >> im[0];
  cap1 >> im[1];

  // check which of im[i] is non empty and do something with it
}
```

Comment: I think this method will cause frame losses if the two cameras have different frame rates (different lighting conditions or different cameras).